# Books similar to Polya's Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning, but in the context of advanced level mathematics

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I enjoy the book *Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning* by G.Polya, but it is mainly about guess in elementary mathematics. Could anyone please recommend a similar book discussing applications of plausible reasoning (that may include inductions, analogies, looking for patterns and links, calculating the odds, or an other methods mentioned in Polya's book) to obtain results in undergraduate-level mathematics (like real and complex analysis, abstract algebra, etc.)?